# How to delete old log files using shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

my log directory containing following files

access.log

defaultAuditrecorder20110901.log (this is 31st jun generated log file)

defaultAuditrecorder20110901.log (this is 1 st aug generated log file)

defaultAuditrecorder20110902.log (this is 2 nd aug generated log file)

defaultAuditrecorder.log         (this is currentdey running log file)

mng1.log001

mng1.log002

mng1.log003  .............. so on......

my requirement is using shell script i need to **only delete defaultauditrecord log files except current and previous day**.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [`logrotate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). It lets you delete (or compress, rotate, etc.) log files, and is quite configurable. It is likely more robust than rolling your own script.

Edit: Here's a [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/).

Comment: peddireddy : It's quite rude of you to demand a "full script" of someone when they give you a superior solution that demands some work from you. The problem of deleting and handling logs is pretty much solved using logrotate and using that will likely prevent a large number of disasters you'll have to otherwise face.

Answer (score 2):

the simplest mechanism is to use the find command.

```
find /var/log -mtime +2d -a -type f -print
```

This will find all files that have been modified more than 2 days ago. To chain it into a removal command you would use:

```
find /var/log -mtime +2d -a -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

In this example, I used /var/log, you would substitute the directory that contains the logs. The reason for using the -print0 and the xargs -0, is that if the file contains whitespace it would not get processed by the rm command properly.

Comment: why not just use the `-delete` flag for `find`?

Comment: Except where it's not supported (busybox find). I tend to use logrotate for things like this